# Binding to UserControl property inside tooltip not working

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, binding, dependency-properties

I am trying to do some simple binding to a property inside my usercontrol. Does anyone know why this doesn't work? It works when the TextBlock is outside the Tooltip.

Thanks!

MasterPage.cs:

```
MyUserControlInstance.DisplayName = "Test";
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Template="{StaticResource ToolTipTemplate}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Path=DisplayName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTip>
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
```

MyUserControl.cs

```
public static DependencyProperty DisplayNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayName", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));
public string DisplayName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayNameProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tooltip has PlacementTarget property that specifies the UI element that has the Tooltip

```
<TextBlock.ToolTip> 
    <ToolTip  
         DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}">  <!-- tooltip content --> 
     </ToolTip> 
</TextBlock.ToolTip>
```

Answer (score 2):

Element to Element Binding is not working for ToolTips, because tooltip has it's own element tree. [Here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/) is one way to do it

Answer (score 1):

A tool tip is considered to be a control in its own right and therefore cant see its direct parent.  The binding inside it cant access the UserControl Element as it knows nothing about it.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tom_mathews/binding-a-tooltip-in-xaml) for a couple of solutions to this problem.